# finding binomial co-effecient modulo prime number,Interview street challenge

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, largenumber, binomial-coefficients

I have done a lot of work on this but couldnt find the answer for larger test cases

## Problem statement

In mathematics, binomial coefficients are a family of positive integers that occur as coefficients in the binomial theorem.    C(n,k) denotes the number of ways of choosing k objects from n different objects.

However when n and k are too large, we often save them after modulo operation by a prime number P. Please calculate how many binomial coefficients of n become to 0 after modulo by P.

### Input

The first of input is an integer T , the number of test cases.

Each of the following T lines contains 2 integers,  n and prime P.

### Output

For each test case, output a line contains the number of  \tbinom nks (0<=k<=n)  each of which after modulo operation by P is 0.

### Sample Input

```
3
2 2
3 2
4 3
```

### Sample Output

```
1
0
1
```

### Constraints:

- T is less than 100
- n is less than 10^500.
- P is less than 10^9.

## Attemted solution

i have completed this by using remainder theorem in binomial coeffecients

```
         #C(n,m) mod p
         #n=l*p+t
         #m=m*p+s
         #then C(n,r) mod p=0 when (t<s or t=0)

         inp1 = raw_input()
         N=int(inp1)
         result=[]
         for i in range(N):
            inp = raw_input()
            a, b = [long(x) for x in inp.split(' ')]
           j=0
           #n=lp+t
           t=a%b
           t=t+1
           l=a/b
           j=l*(b-t)
           result.append(j)
        for i in range(N):
           print result[i]
```

above condition is satisfied for small numbers

sample test case

> n=18794630773460178101742670493883191390743597826923079533199667903991430393463990462500322752062869664969026409174076912867222446746310051635510258172105034070506806228555577773599018819952185016092141574603857551738968553782672643049704163674318579695215402562964641111900657274032612661770435202254364177910753450214277150377049334509093906874400306682949871260040370515062243982543271073443613028133844603853807066311479739789908983610180228625059956919930500586048799830730348503994503184106117058

p= 177080341

my output is

> 2296508200406431043037217853758906667313789305876262916681342008001095232916608835588093082038358975456171743147798282523487485386336553910277635713985851142371010771392102277877640275384064735398164190968282400640398659343189330639672472613876688344609533340662724884373078840434716174167873375700938597411315754265893890741730938202927739246687866166994143001482839656000969674716959277820008958538229366474207686428750934149471409162993083541475267772950721250234982686128039722553219836725588488

expected output is

> 18794630773460178101742635959946548665553041135822283621364103266511586625905046107130878283695016799933475657268010472422112556606280021574002866456544310584537519228161286450725015989697306855581489155139723025246780552510467580791551824827637581156204185887378181074365453150481221030356075255000460025095384537510111086396988416046942446776262625161326885418101128327416784858513888616089287333560469336094431461981368825028447505354473183546488856594449627370807707483671453574074503184106117059

Comment: After a first computation of my own, I tend to agree with *your* result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula's off.

You're calculating l * (p - t - 1).

This formula doesn't work if there are factors of p^2, p^3, etc.  This would occur when l > p (and possibly if m > p too).

For small numbers, try n = 10, p = 3 to see what I'm talking about.  Your calculation would return 3 values of r where 10 C r mod 3 = 0, but in fact, there are 7.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the actual formula is.  I tried to figure that out before posting, but didn't.

Comment: Just call the function again  <pre> def fun1(a,b): if a>=b: j=0 t=a%b l=a/b j=l*(b-t-1) return j+((t+1)*fun1(l,b)) else: return 0 inp1 = raw_input() N=int(inp1) result=[] for i in range(N): inp = raw_input() a, b = [long(x) for x in inp.split(' ')] j=fun1(a,b) #n=lp+t result.append(j) for i in range(N): print result[i]

Answer (score 15):

You can look at it from the other end: How many `nCr` are *not* divisible by `p`? There's a rather simple formula for that.

#### Preliminaries:

The binomial coefficient `nCr` is given by

```
nCr = n! / (r! * (n-r)!)
```

so the multiplicity `v_p(nCr)` of `p` in `nCr` - the exponent of `p` in the prime factorisation of `nCr` - is

```
v_p(nCr) = v_p(n!) - v_p(r!) - v_p((n-r)!)
```

The multiplicity of `p` in `n!` can be easily determined, a well known way to calculate it is

```
v_p(n!) =  ∑ floor(n/p^k)
         k > 0
```

If you look at this formula considering the base-`p` expansion of `n`, you can see that

```
v_p(n!) = (n - σ_p(n)) / (p - 1)
```

where `σ_p(k)` is the sum of the digits of the base-`p` representation of `k`. Thus

```
v_p(nCr) = (n - σ_p(n) - r + σ_p(r) - (n-r) + σ_p(n-r)) / (p - 1)
         = (σ_p(r) + σ_p(n-r) - σ_p(n)) / (p - 1)
```

#### Conclusion:

`nCr` is *not* divisible by the prime `p` if and only if the addition of `r` and `n-r` has no carry in base `p`.

Because that is exactly when `σ_p(a + b) = σ_p(a) + σ_p(b)`. A carry in the addition occurs when the sum of corresponding digits of `a` and `b` (plus possibly the carry-in if there was already a carry produced for less significant digits) is `>= p`, then the corresponding digit in the sum is reduced by `p` and the next more significant digit increased by 1, reducing the digital sum by `p - 1`.

We have a carry-free addition `n = r + (n-r)` in base `p` if for each digit `d_k` in `n`'s base-`p` expansion, the corresponding digit of `r` is less than or equal to `d_k`. The admissible choices of the digits of `r` are independent, hence the total number is the product of the count of choices for the individual digits.

The number of `nCr` not divisible by the prime `p` is

```
ND(n,p) = ∏(d_k + 1)
```

where the `d_k` are the digits in `n`'s base `p` expansion,

```
    m
n = ∑ d_k * p^k
   k=0
```

Since there are `n+1` (nonzero) binomial coefficients `nCr` for a given `n`, the number of (nonzero) binomial coefficients `nCr` divisible by `p` is

```
        m
n + 1 - ∏ (d_k + 1)
       k=0
```

with the above base `p` expansion of `n`.

Using [Michael's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11877334/1011995) `n = 10`, `p = 3`,

```
10 = 1*3^0 + 0*3^1 + 1*3^2
```

so there are `(1+1)*(0+1)*(1+1) = 4` coefficients `10Cr` not divisible by 3 and `10 + 1 - 4 = 7` divisible by 3.

```
def divisibleCoefficients(n,p):
    m, nondiv = n, 1
    while m > 0:
        nondiv = nondiv * ((m % p) + 1)
        m = m // p
    return (n + 1 - nondiv)
```

Comment: brilliant explanation....could u give some pointers to materials discussing divisibility,primes,pollards rho etc...btw the result u just derived is a corollary of lucas' theorem

Comment: thank you for your answer! I found this paper, might be useful to someone http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math140/Suppl0.pdf